# Compile headers for errors using cmake

Tags: cmake

**Background**

I have a number of headers as part of a library (call it A) and are also used externally from other libraries (call it C).

I'd like to compile as part A's compilation to ensure the headers are self-contained. (Currently, this involves compiling C and if there are issues, re-compile A & make a new release).

**Question**

What's the best way to compile headers and discard the results? I am only interested in their successful compilation.

I am thinking of copy and rename them as cpp files (it's a C++ project) and then create a library out of them to check errors. But is there a simpler solution?

My aim is to the command-line equivalent of

```
g++ [compile_flags] -c header.hpp
```

and check for errors but not interested in the produced files.

I'd like something that works with cmake 3.13.5 (or older).

Thanks

Comment: maybe [precompile headers](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/command/target_precompile_headers.html)?

Comment: I tried it. But it requires cmake 3.16 whereas I'd like something in <= 3.13.5.

Comment: Your header files contain inline functions and templates? The compiler will not instantiate and compile those, unless they are used somewhere. Does your library have a test suite for the code in those headers? Compile that to check for errors.

Comment: @Enno There are no templates or inline functions. Just classes, structs and other PODs. As noted in the 'background', this aim to compile some headers when making A so that we don't end up with failures when compiling C. Unfortunately, the test suites are mostly done as part of C's build which is too late. Otherwise this isn't a serious issue - just trying to save few minutes in our dev cycle.

Comment: So your goal is merely to make sure that these headers have no missing includes or syntax errors? In that case, if you just include all of them from an otherwise empty .cpp file and compile that, will that not do what you want?

Comment: @Enno yes, to some extent. But one header might unintentionally hide issues in other (e.g., say header5 needs structX but doesn't include the header for it. Lumping all together might be hide this because header1 includes the structX's header). It'd be quite straight-forward if they're cpp files (that's why I suggested renaming them as cpp and then compile them to a library (`add_library`) and discard it). I just wondered if there's more cmake-y solution to deal with headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I ran into the same question recently, let me show the solution I went with:

When you list the header files in your target's sources and only use relative paths below the current path (i.e. no `..` in the paths), you can use a function like the following to compile a separate *cpp* file for each *hpp* file.

```
function(check_headers target)
    # build object library used to "compile" the headers
    add_library(${target}_headers OBJECT)
    target_link_libraries(${target}_headers PRIVATE ${target})
    target_include_directories(${target}_headers PRIVATE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
    # add a proxy source file for each header in the target source list
    get_target_property(TARGET_SOURCES ${target} SOURCES)
    foreach(TARGET_SOURCE ${TARGET_SOURCES})
        if ("${TARGET_SOURCE}" MATCHES ".*\.hpp$")
            set(HEADER_SOURCEFILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${TARGET_SOURCE}.cpp")
            file(WRITE "${HEADER_SOURCEFILE}" "#include \"${TARGET_SOURCE}\"")
            target_sources(${target}_headers PRIVATE "${HEADER_SOURCEFILE}")
        endif()
    endforeach()
endfunction()
```

It adds an object library that compiles each header file in the given target.

Comment: I ended up doing something like this (as alluded to in my comments). One thing to note is that the "library" needs to be deleted.

Comment: I would disagree on that, since the resulting library is just another build artifact like test binaries etc. that are usually not part of what is being used or even installed on the system afterwards. Also, such a header self-sufficiency check would probably more often be used by library developers or even CI jobs than library users, so a simple on/off flag should eliminate the potential overhead (both in terms of runtime and space) of building this object library.